# Show nth:div 1, when i click nth: anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hide, getelementbyid

Good Evening helpful people of stackoverflow,

I want to hide the **clicked ** `.project-tile-normal` and show the appropriate description div `.detail-tile`.

I read through some articles regarding my question, but i run into a logical brickwall in my head. Needlessly to say, i'm a beginner in jquery and maybe there is a better way to do that, i just didn't find it.

Here's what i found so far as "answers":
[Hide Children, Show nth Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035337/jquery-hide-children-show-nth-child) - *the closest answer to my question*
[Show and Hide Several Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213457/show-and-hide-several-divs-when-clicking-on-links) - *this solution makes my head dizzy*

My HTML consists of two rows of divs, similar to that simplified representation:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class=".project-tile-normal">some pictures</div>
 <div class=".project-tile-normal"></div>
 <div class=".project-tile-normal"></div>

 <div class=".detail-tile">description</div>
 <div class=".detail-tile"></div>
 <div class=".detail-tile"></div>
</div>
```

This is what i have so far coded:

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.project-tile-normal').on("click", function() {
 if( $(this).hasClass("active") ) {
     $(this).fadeOut(150);
 } else {
   var itemid = '#div' + $(this).attr('target'); // my own try to get the Element of the divs.
   console.log(itemid);
   $(this).addClass("active");
 $(".detail-tile").removeClass("hidden");
 }
});

$('button').on("click", function(){
  $(".detail-tile").addClass("hidden");
  $(".project-tile-normal").fadeIn(150);
  $(".project-tile-normal").removeClass("active");
 });
});//document ready
```

Should i put all the Items in an array and then count it out? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that your `class` attributes in the HTML should not contain any `.` characters.

With regard to the JS, you can link elements by index by retrieving the `index()` from the clicked element then selecting the matching required element using `eq()`, something like this:

```
$('.project-tile-normal').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.detail-tile').hide().eq(index).show();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nretbrce/)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! The class attribute was indeed careless mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the `.` before the class attribute since there is no need of it. As per the jQuery code there is no need of it. If you are using `.` you need to escape it using `\.`, in the jQuery selector it may be like `$('.\\.project-tile-normal')` .

---

Now you can do the rest using **[`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** and **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq)**,

```js
$('.project-tile-normal').click(function() {
  // you can use toggle if you want toggle between the show and hidden
  // else use show method
  $('.detail-tile').eq($(this).index()).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="project-tile-normal">some pictures</div>
  <div class="project-tile-normal">1</div>
  <div class="project-tile-normal">2</div>

  <div class="detail-tile">description</div>
  <div class="detail-tile">1</div>
  <div class="detail-tile">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your classes wrong in your HTML. It'll be **project-tile-normal** instead of **.project-tile-normal**. On doing that you'll be finding your events working. Then you can actually follow those tutorials to pull off your desired behavior on project title click.